# Regex match a line if it contains a specific word

Tags: regex, xml

I have a long xml text and I want to match each product that is available. The text is made of products that are structured like this:

```
<product>
    ...
    <available>instock</available>
    ...
</product>
```

I can match all products with this regex

```
((?s)<product>.*?<\/product>)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/kz8cn1/1

However, I want to match, only those products that have an 'instock' value in their  tag.

My solution is this:

```
((?s)<product>(?=.*?\binstock\b).*?<\/product>)
```

Unfortunately, this works only partially as I believe the lookaround regex is not contained to the match group which results in products with 'outofstock' values being matched as well.
Here is my example:
https://regex101.com/r/AHlC0K/1

How should I change my regex so that the lookaround works only in the context of the match?

Comment: No - use a proper `xml` parser in the programming language of your choice - there are plenty and that is what they were made for.

Comment: And if you cannot use any XML parser, the last resort is `(?s)<product>(?:(?!</?product>|\binstock\b).)*\binstock\b(?:(?!</?product>).)*</product>`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJsXPG/1). Not at all efficient, rather unreadable regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XML parser. If there is none you can use use

```js
(?s)<product>(?=(?:(?!<\/?product>).)*?\binstock\b).*?<\/product>
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hmLk4M/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <product>                '<product>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        product>                 'product>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    instock                  'instock'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  product>                 'product>'
```